# Calculate central point latitude / longitude for multiple cities

Tags: python-3.x, geolocation

I have a spreadsheet with cities in Brazil and the latitude and longitude of each city. This spreadsheet also contains the regions to which each city belongs. I need to obtain the central latitude and longitude of each region, considering the cities in that region. How to calculate this with Python?

data sample:

[image]

Based on the sample above, I need to calculate the central latitude and longitude of the region named LESTE RONDONIENSE.

Comment: Could the mathematical mean of the cities make sense? -or- Do you want to define the centre as where the tourists want to be with hotels?

Comment: Yes, mathematical mean of the cities make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the mean or median of the cities make sense, read the file with `pd.read_excel()` or `pd.read_csv()` and use `groupby()`;

```
data = pd.read_csv("cities.csv")
data.groupby("NM_MESO").mean()
```